# row number for each table row created by dir-paginate angularJs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dirpagination

How can set row number for each table row created by dir-paginate angularJs.
I use two way code but two way have incorrect and set error.

First way :

```
    <tr dir-paginate='customer in Customers| itemsPerPage: 10'>
        <td>{{rowNum=(rowNum+1)}}</td>
        <td>{{customer.fName}}</td>
        <td>{{customer.lName}}</td>
    </tr>

<script>
 (function(){
    var app = angular.module('customerApp', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
    app.controller('customer', ['$scope', '$http',  function($scope, $http){
        $scope.rowNum = 1;
   }]);
})();
</script>
```

Second way :

```
<tr dir-paginate='customer in Customers| itemsPerPage: 10'>
        <td>{{getRowNum()}}</td>
        <td>{{customer.fName}}</td>
        <td>{{customer.lName}}</td>
    </tr>

<script>
 (function(){
    var app = angular.module('customerApp', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
    app.controller('customer', ['$scope', '$http',  function($scope, $http){
        $scope.rowNum = 1;
        $scope.getRowNum = function(){
            return ++$scope.rowNum;
        };
   }]);
})();
</script>
```

Why i can't increment `$scope.rowNum` from function and ng-bind ?

Comment: May you provide us a codepen oder fiddlejs sample?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think {{$index+1}} should work

image with index + pagination -> {{(currentPage-1)*pageSize +$index+1}} 
[image]

Comment: I tested this code before but number reset when the page change . but i want when page is two the row number continue from prev page .

Comment: Ok If you use currentPage and pageSize like the demo of dir-pagination you could also do it mathematically with {{(currentPage-1)*pageSize +$index+1}}

<li dir-paginate="customer in Customers| itemsPerPage: pageSize" current-page="currentPage">

  $scope.currentPage = 1;
  $scope.pageSize = 10;

Comment: I just added it to http://plnkr.co/edit/Wtkv71LIqUR4OhzhgpqL?p=preview
and it worked. Do you have defined $scope.currentPage and $scope.pageSize?

Comment: i test it but when page change number row begin from 1 . but i want continue the number if page has 2 row number shoud 11 if perPage 10

Comment: I added a image to my original answer. I don't get it why you get NaN, if you defined $scope.pageSize and $scope.currentPage. Also you can see that {{(currentPage-1)*pageSize +$index+1}}  should work with pagination as you mentioned. 

An other opinion would be to add a index through a loop.

Comment: i know why your code not work . i omited current-page='currentPage' inside <tr> element . thanks